# Default in SharePoint Online =[ME] is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, default-value

If I create a string field in a library, using as default value =[ME] doesn't work for Microsoft files extensions.... but for other extensions works fine.
Somebody knows why?

I would believe if SharePoint is Microsoft, their extension files (Word, Excel, etc) would be integrated and working better than other extension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I misunderstood the question, I was thinking you were talking about views, not new/edit forms.

This functionality isn't possible out of the box, defaulting person/group fields to the current user. You'll need some script to look at the `_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName` and push that into your field.

Comment: When I try to create a person field, I can not assign any default value. So how does this work?